# Circle with 2 strokes and gradient

Tags: android

1. How can I draw shape like attached image.

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:shape="oval">
   <stroke
       android:width="8dp"
       android:color="#00A79E"/>

   <solid
       android:color="#e5e5e5"/>
   ```

[image]

2. Using 9-Patch Image give me broken image
   [image]

Comment: Your nine patch hasn't been made correctly, because you can actually do this by using 9 patches.

Comment: just rename the file like 'x.9.png' and then select the marker. and save, close it. Call in background as 'x'.

Comment: No, it doesn't work like that. There are **rules** to follow when **building a 9 patch**, to make it work properly.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can achieve layout as you want as per you pin it in question by using **Layer-list**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="oval">
            <stroke android:color="#24744f" android:width="10dp"/>
            <solid android:color="#fff"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item android:top="10dp" android:bottom="10dp" android:left="10dp" android:right="10dp">
        <shape android:shape="oval">
            <gradient android:angle="90" android:startColor="@color/colorPrimary"/>
            <stroke android:color="#fff" android:width="10dp"/>
        </shape>
    </item>

    <item
        android:bottom="40dp"
        android:drawable="@drawable/ic_launcher_foreground"
        android:left="40dp"
        android:right="40dp"
        android:top="40dp" />
</layer-list>
```

And the result look like attached image,

[image]

Comment: what If need some text in replace of android icon.

Comment: @faisal, you need to set this gradient shape as background of a View and set text to Textview.

Comment: yes, doing this as you suggesting, but the shape became oval.

Comment: No problem you can give fix height and width inside gradient file, so the circle shape become a as it 

`<size android:width="250dp" android:height="250dp"/>`

Comment: hi @FenilPatel, Is their any way we can connect?

Comment: I know that, can you drop me a mail?

Comment: or whatsapp kind off thing

Comment: you are working with some company or as a freelancer

Comment: let me know during what time you are usually available

Answer (score 3):

You can use [**`layer-list`**](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#LayerList)

> A LayerDrawable is a drawable object that manages an array of other drawables. Each drawable in the list is drawn in the order of the list—the last drawable in the list is drawn on top

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="oval">
            <solid android:color="#e5e5e5" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item android:top="10dp" android:bottom="10dp" android:left="10dp" android:right="10dp">
    <shape android:shape="oval">
        <gradient android:angle="90" android:startColor="@color/colorPrimary"/>
        <stroke android:color="#ff00" android:width="10dp"/>
    </shape>
</item>

    <item
        android:bottom="40dp"
        android:drawable="@drawable/ic_launcher_round"
        android:left="40dp"
        android:right="40dp"
        android:top="40dp" />
</layer-list>
```

**OUTPUT**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Make two drawable file for this task

First drawable for stroke:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="oval">
    <stroke
        android:width="8dp"
        android:color="#00A79E" />



</shape>
```

Second for solid color:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="oval">


    <solid android:color="#e5e5e5" />

</shape>
```

Apply this drawable as background in layout.xml like this

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/test"
        android:padding="@dimen/diam15dp">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/test2"
            android:padding="@dimen/diam15dp"

            android:text="sdadasdad" />


    </LinearLayout>
```

Change padding according to your need.
Hope this will help you..

Answer (score 0):

This [Layer List Drawable](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#LayerList) is exactly what you wanted.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <!-- larger circle at the back -->
    <item android:gravity="center">
        <shape android:shape="oval">

            <solid android:color="#FFFFFF" />

            <stroke
                android:width="5dp"
                android:color="#349fab" />
        </shape>
    </item>

    <!-- inner circle -->
    <item
        android:bottom="10dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:left="10dp"
        android:right="10dp"
        android:top="10dp">
        <shape android:shape="oval">
            <solid android:color="#CCCCCC" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```